# What are the important hardware specifications to look for in a router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

Assuming that I purchase a home wireless router compatible with DD-WRT, I won't care about the feature set and the quality of the original firmware. I shall get everything that DD-WRT has to offer, right?

So, when purchasing a router, what are all the hardware components that one should consider?
Which are the key specifications to look for?
Which hardware specs are obsolete (and therefore can safely be ignored - unless it's a sign that the router itself is obsolete)?
Which hardware specs represent the latest step in the evolution of router hardware?

To take a trivial example, a random router offers:
- LAN Ports - 4
- WAN Ports - N/A
- RS-232 Port - N/A
I know what LAN ports are, and I know I need a couple of those :).
However, I could look within wikipedia what the WAN and RS-232 ports are for and try to guess from there whether it's new technology, old technology, something that I would want or something that I can ignore...

Can you help me compile a list of hardware specifications and roughly sort them by importance?    Thanks.

The goal is to build a kind of mental map so that I know what to look for when going shopping for a router.

EDIT:
Why was this question closed for being off-topic, because it is supposedly a "question seeking for hardware shopping recommendations"???
Where do I ask a shopping recommendation???
I am simply asking for a list of key hardware components that one must pay attention to, not asking which grade/type/level/etc. to chose!
Such a waste of time.
Anyway, I have since found other sites that provide the answers I was looking for. Now that I understand better what matters, I can compare myself and chose myself.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I would look into what the software has to offer as some very heavily on features, look for build quality, price, reviews, hardware specifications and if you see a number or anything that sparks interest then do a bit of research on it.